# How to store results of the foreach which is a list into variable and display it in popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, foreach

I have two foreach in same table and the second foreach generate a list of Serial No (i aslo mark that with **) and when i see result of my second foreach in browser is a long list of Serial No ,which is just destroy the whole table (as you in Screenshots) and as you see brings up a Serial No for each item, is there any way I can show them all at once in a Popup window? or How can i solve this to display just one simple text as link for exampel (Click here) and than when user Click on link popup comes out and show Serial No.

- IMAGE - ScreenShots - Updated:[Screenshot of Table "Serial No"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyZ0I.png)

The Code in View :

```
    <div class="card-content table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="text-primary">
                <tr>
                    <th>Item number</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Totally ordered</th>
                    <th>Serial Number</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach (var FieldShipment in Model.OrdreDetailDeliveryLineOpens)
                {

                    <tr>

                        <td>@FieldShipment.VarenummerDeliverdLineOpenOrdre</td>
                        <td>@FieldShipment.BeskrivelseDeliverdLineOpenOrdre</td>
                        <td>@string.Format("{0:N0}", FieldShipment.Qu)</td>

                        <td>
                          ** @foreach (var SerialNo in FieldShipment.SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre) 
                            {

                                @SerialNo //loop Serial No

                            } **

                        </td>
                        <td>@FieldShipment.ShippingAgentDeliverdLineOpenOrdre</td>
                        <td>@FieldShipment.TrackAndTraceDeliverdLineOpenOrdre</td>
                        <td><a target="_blank" class="tl" title="Track & Trace" href="@FieldShipment.TrackLinkDeliverdLineOpenOrdre">Track</a></td>


                    </tr>

                }


            </tbody>


        </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: You could simply add a `<br>` after each serial number to put them onto new lines

Comment: i did before ,but what if i have 100 Serial No ! and should display to customers , it will be nice have text as link ,when customer click on it , popup comes out

Comment: I would add a delimiter (not necessary a `<br />`, it can only be a `,`) and a maximum size (`overflow`?), then show all the data in a tooltip when you hover the incomplete text...

Comment: @SmartDev would you give me an example with my code :) if its possible :)

Comment: I've added an answer...

Comment: use `@{   ...    }` to set the `SerialNos` outside the `td`...

Comment: @SmartDev thx its fine now , would give me idea how make pop up or something , i read the tooltip but i cant figure out .i really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like (although not testes, but you get the idea):

```
// join your serial numbers in one string
var SerialNos = String.Join(", ", FieldShipment.SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre);
```

Then in your view use a `title`:

```
<td title="@SerialNos" style="max-height: 100px; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow-y:hidden">
  @SerialNos
</td>
```

and you can enrich this with a `tooltip`, if you have one available (like the [Bootstrap tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/) for example) or even a `popup`.

Comment: Thx :) just question where should i replace this : var SerialNos = String.Join(", ", FieldShipment.SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre);

Comment: i just update question with new  Screenshots ,where you see whats happend its just repeat  Serial Nos .

Comment: and the code in my view :  foreach (var SerialNo in FieldShipment.SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre)
                                        {

                                            var SerialNos = String.Join(", ", FieldShipment.SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre);

                                            <td title="@SerialNos" style="max-height: 100px; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow-y:hidden">
                                                @SerialNos
                                            </td>

                                        }

Comment: i remove the foreach but its not gonna work i get error in td under SerialNos and my code :var SerialNos = @String.Join(", ", FieldShipment.SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre);

                                            <td title="@SerialNos" style="max-height: 100px; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow-y:hidden">
                                                @SerialNos
                                            </td>

Comment: Or if its possible sir , would you please post the whole code , to better understanding :) if its possible :)